# Node.js и облачные хостинги

Tags: веб-программирование, node.js, хостинг

Приветствую, недавно встретился с облачным хостингом jelastic на reg.ru (не реклама). Понравилось удобство разворачивания приложения и иные фичи.

Но всё же интересно как данное решение будет себя вести в production ?

Какие плюсы имеет и какие минусы между "купить сервер и держать проект на своём сервере" и "использовать облачный хостинг" ? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос - не реклама. А вот ответ к нему - реклама :)

Comment: @PashaPash, то есть я вообще не могу тут ни о чем спросить ? Если я с этим встретился, то всё или сам проходи этот тернистый путь или просто брось это, но не перенимай опыта у других ?

Comment: Владислав Сироштан - можете, ваш вопрос хороший (на мой взгляд). Просто стоит отмечать как спам ответы вроде того, который был дан ниже (с аккаунта Jelastic, с маркетинговым "платформа способна удовлетворить требования самых опытных разработчиков"), и который я удалил.

Comment: @PashaPash, буду знать )